# Dynamic perPage Variable in Laravel vis Select

Tags: pagination, laravel, laravel-4

I'm submitting a form to the index() action of a resource controller but it' scaling the store() method. Here's my code.

http://paste.laravel.com/rru

I'm trying to dynamically change the $perPage variable to adjust the pagination amount via a select box that is submitted using jQuery. Any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no `resource` key available when opening a form. The `index` method on a resource controller is routed as a `GET` request. So because your form is opening as a `POST` request by default it's posting to the current URI which results in the request ending up at your `store` method.

If you're trying to update the pagination then why don't you send it as a `GET` and use the query string (as the paginator does).

Comment: This is how I did it in the end. Thanks.